# Promises not waiting for resolve on FTP stream

Tags: promise, chaining

I have a number of servers to query for logfile information present on them.
To do so I have set-up a FTP connection which is used as a dynamic promise chain to allow all the data to be streamed & processed before proceeding to the next server.

Somehow when I receive the data back it seems as if all servers have sent the correct data but some processed objects seem to be empty. This leads me to believe that for some reason the next server gets queried before the previous data has been processed.

Below code is iterating over each server, streaming their data and processing it upon end connection.

```
let data = "";
let chain = q.when();

for (var i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
    let server = {
        host: servers[i].ipaddress,
        user: servers[i].user,
        password: servers[i].password
    }

    let serverName = servers[i].name;
    let accumulate = fetchData(data, server, serverName); 

    chain = chain.then(function() {    
        accumulate.then(function (result) { // <-- Connects to server & streams logfile data.
            processData(result); // <-- Processes the data received
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result); <-- Result is undefined upon resolving processData
        });
    });
}
```

Below code is fetching the streamed data from FTP and resolving the result so that it can be processed in the next promise.

```
function fetchData(data, server, serverName) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
    let ftp = new Client();
    ftp.connect(server);
    ftp.on('ready', function () {
        ftp.get(setCurrentTextFile(), function (err, stream) {
            if (err) throw err;
            stream.once('close', function () {ftp.end()}); 
            stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
                data += chunk
            }).on('end', function () {
                let result = {
                    "serverName" : serverName,
                    "data" : data
                }
                resolve(result) // <-- Has all data for all servers
            }); 
        });
    });
});
}

function processData(result) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        // Do stuff with log files and place in a list
        console.log(list); // <-- is showing all data correctly for all servers
        resolve(list);    // <-- returns undefined   
    })
}
```

Rejections have been omitted but are accounted for and are not being called upon execution. The code is executing normally but some servers are just returning empty objects whilst console.logging the processed data does show that info.

I am at a loss and would certainly appreciate a helping hand.

Comment: Is your `processData` function really asynchronous?

Comment: You're missing to `return` the `processData(result)` in the `accumulate.then(…)` callback

Comment: You must either put the `let accumulate = fetchData(data, server, serverName);` inside the `chain` callback to get a sequential execution, or you should not use a chain but rather `Promise.all`.

Comment: You are correct with the return statement, @Bergi that did resolve the undefined issue. 

However some servers are still returning nothing whilst they definitely have x amount of rows. 

https://gyazo.com/d09cf642330a6d335a6ea658e435a808 
The numbers are the amount of lines the logfiles have so they are definitely there.

Comment: In `.then(function(result) { console.log(result); })`, `result` will be the result arising from the last element of the `servers` array.
If you are expecting the data from all servers to be logged, then you will need a mechanism for accumulating the results. 

As written, there's no such mechanism.

Passing `data` (empty string) at each `fetchData()` call won't do that job since fetchData's member `data` will not refer back to the original outer member `data`. 

I wonder if that's the root cause of the code not behaving as you expect?

Comment: It seemed everything was working just fine, the fact that I was checking timestamps for certain information and only proceed to extract data when that condition was met, made my script break because some servers were not running in the timezone I was checking and therefore not populating that data. So all in all it was working fine. Also removed the q.when which in the end was unnecessary. Thanks to everyone for their input.